# How to access broadcasted DataFrame in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have created two dataframes which are from Hive tables(PC_ITM and ITEM_SELL) and big in size and I am using those 
frequently in the SQL query by registering as table.But as those are big, it is taking much time 
to get the query result.So I have saved them as parquet file and then read them and registered as temporary table.But still I am not getting good performance so I have broadcasted those data-frames and then registered as tables as below.

```
PC_ITM_DF=sqlContext.parquetFile("path")
val PC_ITM_BC=sc.broadcast(PC_ITM_DF)
val PC_ITM_DF1=PC_ITM_BC
PC_ITM_DF1.registerAsTempTable("PC_ITM")

ITM_SELL_DF=sqlContext.parquetFile("path")
val ITM_SELL_BC=sc.broadcast(ITM_SELL_DF)
val ITM_SELL_DF1=ITM_SELL_BC.value
ITM_SELL_DF1.registerAsTempTable(ITM_SELL)


sqlContext.sql("JOIN Query").show
```

But still I cant achieve performance it is taking same time as when those data frames are not broadcasted.

Can anyone tell if this is the right approach of broadcasting and using it?`

Answer (score 21):

You don't really need to 'access' the broadcast dataframe - you just use it, and Spark will implement the broadcast under the hood. The **[broadcast function](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#broadcast(org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame))** works nicely, and makes more sense that the `sc.broadcast` approach.

It can be hard to understand where the time is being spent if you evaluate everything at once.

You can break your code into steps. The key here will be performing an action and persisting the dataframes you want to broadcast *before* you use them in your join.

```
// load your dataframe
PC_ITM_DF=sqlContext.parquetFile("path")

// mark this dataframe to be stored in memory once evaluated
PC_ITM_DF.persist()

// mark this dataframe to be broadcast
broadcast(PC_ITM_DF)

// perform an action to force the evaluation
PC_ITM_DF.count()
```

Doing this will ensure that the dataframe is

- loaded in memory (persist)
- registered as temp table for use in your SQL query
- marked as broadcast, so will be shipped to all executors

When you now run `sqlContext.sql("JOIN Query").show` you should now see a 'broadcast hash join' in the SQL tab of your Spark UI.

Comment: What is the benefit of broadcasting an RDD? RDD stands for resilient distributed dataset. Broadcasting removes the distributed nature of the RDD. I can see the use case where you collect data from an RDD into memory and broadcast that. I don't believe this is even possible. If you look at this [article](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/05/working-with-apache-spark-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-the-shuffle/) it says.. "to broadcast an RDD you need to first collect() it on the driver node." Have you ever used this in practice or testing?

Comment: @AlexNaspo yes, I use this all the time. The benefit is that the data is completely available on all the nodes - it's no longer distributed - which makes for improved performance when joining. For example, consider a DataFrame containing every person in the USA and their zip code, and then a table containing zip code -> state. Joining these requires massive amounts of shuffling. Broadcast the relatively tiny zip->state dataframe to all nodes removes the need to shuffle.

Comment: You are broadcasting the dataframe which is held in memory, not distributed. Is that correct? Spark suggests adding a partitioner to your data to reduce the amount of shuffle when joining. @kirkbroadhurt

Comment: I am telling Spark that the dataframe should be broadcast. It remains 'distributed' until it is required (e.g. for a join), at which time Spark's Catalyst optimizer understands that I want it to send an entire copy of the dataframe to each node.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood. This is under the condition where the dataframe fits in memory.  In your example of zipcodes, that works great. In the case of a distributed dataframe larger than your memory, broadcasting does not seem like the correct approach. In which case a combination of persisting and partitioning your data would be a solution that works with any size of data.

Comment: Of course.  It depends greatly on the size of the dataframe. In the example I gave, the optimizer might be able to detect that the zipcode table is small enough to broadcast - but it might not. Broadcasting the small table will improve performance by orders of magnitude.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101350/discussion-between-kirk-broadhurst-and-alex-naspo).

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst  Using RDD you need to collect it and assign to a new variable. As for the dataframes by `broadcast(df)` is the `df` sent to all the nodes? Or do i need to assign it to a new variable?

Comment: I find this doesn't work in my SparkSQL query. It turns out `broadcast` is a function which returns a new dataframe (broadcasted one), unlike `cache` which is a method. So what works is just register the result of `broadcast` as a temp table, then call it in a SQL query.

Comment: @piggybox, how did you determine Kirk's solution did not work?  I want to try your solution and Kirk's, but how can I determine if each solution is working or not working?

Comment: @MarkRajcok you can check the query plan or the DAG in Spark console to see if a broadcasting actually happens or not

Answer (score 0):

I would cache the rdds in memory. The next time they are needed, spark will read the RDD from memory rather than generating the RDD from scratch each time. Here is a link to the quick start [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#caching).

```
val PC_ITM_DF = sqlContext.parquetFile("path")
PC_ITM_DF.cache()
PC_ITM_DF.registerAsTempTable("PC_ITM")

val ITM_SELL_DF=sqlContext.parquetFile("path")
ITM_SELL_DF.cache()
ITM_SELL_DF.registerAsTempTable("ITM_SELL")
sqlContext.sql("JOIN Query").show
```

rdd.cache() is shorthand for `rdd.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)`. There are a few levels of persistence you can choose from incase your data is too big for memory only persistence. Here is a [list of persistence options.](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence) If you want to manually remove the RDD from the cache you can call `rdd.unpersist()`.

If you prefer to broadcast the data. You must first collect it on the driver before you broadcast it. This requires that your RDD fits in memory on your driver (and executers).

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question, which is how to broadcast a DataFrame. Persisting will only help if you are loading it more than once, i.e. reusing. It does not help when joining two distributed datasets.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst He states that the data is large and is used frequently

Comment: @AlexNaspo slightly digressing from the original question: `RDD fits in memory` thus this mean I can not broadcast data until I can collect it in the main memory of the driver? I generally use my own laptop as driver and masters/slaves on a large cluster. So is this a limitation I may face soon?

Comment: According @KirkBroadhurst you can broadcast the RDD and the executors will collect the data when it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment you can not access broadcasted data frame in the SQL query. You can use brocasted data frame through only through data frames.

Refer: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16475

Comment: The solution as for now is to broadcast the df or table in dataframe api first, register the returned value from `broadcast` function as a temp table, then call that temp table inside a SQL query.