# Spark best approach Look-up Dataframe to improve performance

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

Dataframe A (millions of records) one of the column is create_date,modified_date

Dataframe B 500 records has start_date and end_date

Current approach:

`Select a.*,b.* from a join b on a.create_date between start_date and end_date`

The above job takes half hour or more to run.

how can I improve the performance

[image: spark job details]

[image]

Comment: Consider broadcasting dataframe B. See this related question http://stackoverflow.com/a/34932092/2843520

Comment: can we use broadcast in sql statement.

Answer (score 3):

DataFrames currently doesn't have an approach for direct joins like that. It will fully read both tables before performing a join.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16614

You can use the RDD API to take advantage of the `joinWithCassandraTable` function

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.md#using-joinwithcassandratable

Comment: both are in memory dataframe

Answer (score 0):

As others suggested, one of the approach is to broadcast the smaller dataframe. This can be done automatically also by configuring the below parameter.

```
spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold
```

If the dataframe size is smaller than the value specified here, Spark automatically broadcasts the smaller dataframe instead of performing a join. You can read more about this [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#other-configuration-options).