# Broadcast dataframe is not removing shuffle phase (few rows of data)

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, spark-notebook

I am learning spark using databricks community edition notebook. I have created sample data with few rows.
As data is really small it should not have exchange phase in query plan. I tried broadcast too, still I see exchange phase. Do these configuration do not work on DB community edition notebook?

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col,regexp_replace}

val authorBook = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a1" , "b1") , ("a1","b2") , ("a2" , "b3"),("a3" , "b4")))
val schemaColumn = Seq("author","book")
val df = authorBook.toDF(schemaColumn:_*)

val bookSold = sc.parallelize(Seq(("b1",100) , ("b2" , 500) , ("b3" , 400) , ("b4" , 500)) )
val bookSchema = Seq("book" , "sold_copy")
val dfBook = bookSold.toDF(bookSchema:_*)

///val totalBookSold = df.repartition(4,col("book")).join(dfBook.repartition(4,col("book")) , "book")

sc.broadcast(dfBook)
val totalBookSold = df.join(dfBook , "book")
totalBookSold.explain(true)
```

Query plan is same with broadcast and without broadcast

```
    == Physical Plan ==
*(3) Project [book#698, author#697, sold_copy#708]
+- *(3) SortMergeJoin [book#698], [book#707], Inner
   :- Sort [book#698 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(book#698, 200), [id=#2071]
   :     +- *(1) Project [_1#694 AS author#697, _2#695 AS book#698]
   :        +- *(1) Filter isnotnull(_2#695)
   :           +- *(1) SerializeFromObject [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true])._1, true, false) AS _1#694, staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true])._2, true, false) AS _2#695]
   :              +- Scan[obj#693]
   +- Sort [book#707 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      +- Exchange hashpartitioning(book#707, 200), [id=#2079]
         +- *(2) Project [_1#704 AS book#707, _2#705 AS sold_copy#708]
            +- *(2) Filter isnotnull(_1#704)
               +- *(2) SerializeFromObject [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true])._1, true, false) AS _1#704, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true])._2 AS _2#705]
                  +- Scan[obj#703]
```

This link resolved my issue

[Broadcast not happening while joining dataframes in Spark 1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35235450/broadcast-not-happening-while-joining-dataframes-in-spark-1-6)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access broadcasted DataFrame in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34931272/how-to-access-broadcasted-dataframe-in-spark)

Comment: NO , Both questions are different. Given link id about how to use broadcast DF and my question is about query optimization. As Broadcasting small df is widely advertised approach to avoid shuffles.

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting this due to not using broadcast during join.

Try to use following:

```
val totalBookSold = df.join(broadcast(dfBook) , "book")
totalBookSold.explain(true)
```

You must see hint passed in logical plan and will see difference in physical plan.

Similar to this:

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Join UsingJoin(Inner,List(book))
:- Project [_1#3 AS author#6, _2#4 AS book#7]
:  +- SerializeFromObject [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true]))._1, true, false) AS _1#3, staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true]))._2, true, false) AS _2#4]
:     +- ExternalRDD [obj#2]
+- ResolvedHint (broadcast)
   +- Project [_1#13 AS book#16, _2#14 AS sold_copy#17]
      +- SerializeFromObject [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true]))._1, true, false) AS _1#13, assertnotnull(assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true]))._2 AS _2#14]
         +- ExternalRDD [obj#12]

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
book: string, author: string, sold_copy: int
Project [book#7, author#6, sold_copy#17]
+- Join Inner, (book#7 = book#16)
   :- Project [_1#3 AS author#6, _2#4 AS book#7]
   :  +- SerializeFromObject [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true]))._1, true, false) AS _1#3, staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true]))._2, true, false) AS _2#4]
   :     +- ExternalRDD [obj#2]
   +- ResolvedHint (broadcast)
      +- Project [_1#13 AS book#16, _2#14 AS sold_copy#17]
         +- SerializeFromObject [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true]))._1, true, false) AS _1#13, assertnotnull(assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true]))._2 AS _2#14]
            +- ExternalRDD [obj#12]

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Project [book#7, author#6, sold_copy#17]
+- Join Inner, (book#7 = book#16)
   :- Project [_1#3 AS author#6, _2#4 AS book#7]
   :  +- Filter isnotnull(_2#4)
   :     +- SerializeFromObject [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true])._1, true, false) AS _1#3, staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true])._2, true, false) AS _2#4]
   :        +- ExternalRDD [obj#2]
   +- ResolvedHint (broadcast)
      +- Project [_1#13 AS book#16, _2#14 AS sold_copy#17]
         +- Filter isnotnull(_1#13)
            +- SerializeFromObject [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true])._1, true, false) AS _1#13, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true])._2 AS _2#14]
               +- ExternalRDD [obj#12]

== Physical Plan ==
*(2) Project [book#7, author#6, sold_copy#17]
+- *(2) BroadcastHashJoin [book#7], [book#16], Inner, BuildRight
   :- *(2) Project [_1#3 AS author#6, _2#4 AS book#7]
   :  +- *(2) Filter isnotnull(_2#4)
   :     +- *(2) SerializeFromObject [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true])._1, true, false) AS _1#3, staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true])._2, true, false) AS _2#4]
   :        +- Scan ExternalRDDScan[obj#2]
   +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, string, true]))
      +- *(1) Project [_1#13 AS book#16, _2#14 AS sold_copy#17]
         +- *(1) Filter isnotnull(_1#13)
            +- *(1) SerializeFromObject [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true])._1, true, false) AS _1#13, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple2, true])._2 AS _2#14]
               +- Scan ExternalRDDScan[obj#12]
```